# How to get the error (404) page into the ''dist" directory in nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, custom-error-pages

I created an error page as in the documentation and it works.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/views#error-page

In short, I create an `error.vue` file in the `/layouts` directory and optionally pass it a custom `layout`.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 404">Page not found</h1>
    <h1 v-else>An error occurred</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Home page</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['error'],
    layout: 'error' // custom layout
  }
</script>
```

But my product task requires the `404` page to go into the `/dist` directory after the `generate` command.

Like this

```
dist/
--| 200.html
--| 404.html //do not exist for me
```

The following solutions **didn't** help:

1. If I just add a `404` page to the `/pages` directory, then Nuxt will still show its **default** error page.

Is there a laconic way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you need a `404` page at first? Nuxt is handling this for you.

Comment: @kissu The nginx configuration is such that if the page is not found, it expects to find a 404 page to give it. And if he does not find it, then he gives his standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by adding this code to `nuxt.config.js`.

```
router: {
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push({
      name: 'custom',
      path: '*',
      component: resolve('@/pages/404.vue')
    })
  }
},
```

Now `404.vue` is in the `/pages` directory, and the `404.html` page is in the `/dist` directory.

Documentation:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#extendroutes